# Are ip:subnet combinations in ACLs different than everywhere else?

Tags: cisco, ipv4, subnet, acl, network-access

We're trying to debug a connection issue, and I can't find any solid documentation one way or the other. I'm not positive of the hardware we're using, but we can assume Cisco for now, as I doubt there's much difference for this question.

Take the following example ACL entry:

`1800 permit tcp 10.74.10.50/32 10.74.150.21/32 range 10000 19999`

Will this work? I questioned this, as a `/32` traditionally means nothing beyond the subnet ID and broadcast address are usable. I was told that subnetting works differently for ACL entries, and that the `/32` here means that *only* the address given will be permitted.

Could someone let me know which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A /32 mask is often referred to as a host address, and it means a subnet with a single host.  That is normal IP addressing and it works in ACLs or routing or anywhere else you use IP addresses.

One thing to mention:  For Cisco IOS, ACLs are written with a "wildcard" mask, which is the one's complement of the subnet mask.  So 255.255.255.0 would be written as 0.0.0.255.  A /32 would be written as 0.0.0.0.

NX-OS does use the slash notation.

ASAs use the standard net mask.

Answer (score 2):

Cisco router ACLs use wildcard masks for IPv4, not CIDR notation, like you have. A wildcard mask is the inverse of the network mask, so you are counting the number of `0` bits, instead of the number of `1` bits. For a 32-bit mask, you can use the `host` keyword. Numbered, extended ACLs are in the `100` to `199` and `1300` to `1999` range.

You example would be something like:

```
access-list 1800 permit tcp host 10.74.10.50 host 10.74.150.21 range 10000 19999
```

or:

```
access-list 1800 permit tcp 10.74.10.50 0.0.0.0 10.74.150.21 0.0.0.0 range 10000 19999
```